# Include negative value in stacked bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a problem, and I don't know how I can solve this :(

Could you please help me?

The parameter "Fim de Vida" does not plote in grafic[image: My Grafic].

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
enter code here\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \path let \p1=($(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                            -(normalized axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},0)$)
                in node[
                    at={(normalized axis cs:%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                    },
                    anchor={-90*sign(\y1)},yshift={sign(\y1)*2pt}
                ]
                {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
 \pgfplotstableread{
Year    OneCol  SecCol  ThirdCol ForthCol FifthCol SixthCol
1    6.58E-08 1.44E-08 5.42E-08 4.02E-08 2.30E-08 -6.02E-09 
2    2.42E-09 3.17E-10 1.19E-09 8.85E-10 5.07E-10 -1.22E-10
3    1.53E-08 3.17E-10 1.19E-09 8.85E-10 5.54E-10 6.88E-10
}\datatable

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=0.9*\textwidth,
      bar width=0.26cm,
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\footnotesize},
      ybar stacked,
      stack negative=on previous, %<- moved down
      bar width=1em,
      ymin=-5.00E-08,
      axis on top,
      ymax=2.50E-07,
      ymajorgrids = true,
      enlarge x limits={true, abs value=0.75},
      height=8cm,
      nodes near coords={},
      legend style={
      at={(1.1,0.5)},
      anchor=west,
      draw=none },
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels={Cenário Um, Cenário Dois, Cenário Três}
      ]
      \addplot [fill=cyan!70,draw=black!70] table [y index=1] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=green!90,draw=black!70] table [y index=2] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=teal!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=3] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=violet!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=4] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=lime!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=5] {\datatable};
      \addplot [fill=magenta!90,draw=black!70]table [y index=6] {\datatable};
  \legend{Bateria, Estrutura,Motor,Pneu,Uso,Final de Vida}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Impacts by category relative to baseline building with conventional building envelope}
\label{relative}
  \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `stack negative=on previous` with `stack negative=separate`.

But note that one of the negative values is very close to zero. You will not be able to see it in the graph.

Comment: It workssss =) Thank you very much